# Why addEventListener not works into a script runing on vm nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to execute a script in an isolated context using `vm` module of `nodejs`, but, since I don't have control over the script (because scripts comes from users) I can't avoid users to use `addEventListener` method. I need to detect when script throws an error as `try{}catch(){}` doesn't work in this case. I'm using node version `12.19.0` and electronjs version `9.3.1`, Below is the code:

```
var vm = require('vm'),
    fs = require('fs');
var sandbox = {
    createElement: function(tag_name){
        return document.createElement(tag_name);
    }
};
var script = new vm.Script(fs.readFileSync('script_path.js'));

//Create context
vm.createContext( sandbox );

//run
script.runInContext( sandbox );
```

The code fails when `addEventListener` is used in script code, for instance: (script_path.js)

```
var element = createElement('p');
//If addEventListener is needed
element.addEventListener('click', function(){}, false);
```

If I load that script, the window browser (Electron) shows an empty page, and the console is disconnected. If I add a try-catch to handle possible errors, it also not works.

Comment: There is no `document` in Node.

Comment: If i remove `element.addEventListener('click', function(){}, false);` that code works, the `createElement` function is executed because the function was defined out of the script, if i use `document.createElement` directly in the script, i can handle `document is not defined` error